# How to add gif elements to image? (I drew a house and want to make windows clickable)

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, gif

I started to work on one project and it really inspired me to move forward with my coding skills and perform some real action. But I need your advice.

I drew a house with lots of windows and there supposed to be a small gif animation in each window.

How I see it inside my head: firstly there is a static image of house/windows but when I click on certain window, certain gif animation (allocated to this window) starts to play (let's stay, someone starts to play a guitar, cat starts to walk, etc.)

How I see it in form of code: that's the question I want to ask you :D Could you please give me some tips how to start my research? Literally anything can be helpful because after hours of googling I feel even more lost than before.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a look at image maps https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: thanks a lot Adam, that's exactly what I was looking for! <3